# Declare variables in scheduled query BigQuery;

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am developing a scheduled query where I am using the WITH statement to join and filtrate several tables from BigQuery. To filtrate the dates, I would like to declare the following variables:
DECLARE initial, final DATE;

```
SET initial = DATE_TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7,ISOWEEK);
SET final = LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7, ISOWEEK);
```

However, when executing this query, I am getting two results; one for the variables declared (which I am not interested in having them as output), and the WITH statement that is selected at the end (which as the results that I am interested in).

The principal problem is that, whenever I try t connect this scheduled query to a table in Google Data Studio I get the following error:

> Invalid value: configuration.query.destinationTable cannot be set for scripts;

How can I declare a variable without getting it as a result at the end?

Here you have a sample of the code I am trying work in:

```
DECLARE initial, final DATE;
SET initial = DATE_TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7,ISOWEEK);
SET final = LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7, ISOWEEK);
WITH HelloWorld AS (

SELECT shop_date, revenue
FROM fulltable
WHERE shop_date >= initial
  AND shop_date <= final

)
SELECT * from HelloWorld;
```

Comment: Welcome! Based on the code above, can't you simply code in the values directly, instead of using declare, since the dates are dynamic anyway?

Comment: It's what I am ding right now, but I have several 10 codes that are exactly the same and the only thing that changes are these dates (that are scattered around all the coding. The idea of using this variable was to make the code a bit more nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

```
with initial1 as ( select DATE_TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7,ISOWEEK) as initial2),

final1 as ( select LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7, ISOWEEK) as final2),

HelloWorld AS (
SELECT shop_date, revenue
FROM fulltable
WHERE shop_date >= (select initial2 from initial1) AND shop_date <= (select final2 from final1)
)

SELECT * from HelloWorld;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have tried that out and it does work. However, I as looking for something more concise. At the end my objective is to clean out a bit the mess in my code, and with this solution, the coindition is still the a bit too long

Comment: You can achieve it by creating stored procedure. SP allows variable declaration.

Comment: I a not familiar with that procedure, what is SP?

Answer (score 0):

With **config** table having just 1 row and cross-joining it with your table, your query can be written like below.

```sql
WITH config AS (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7,ISOWEEK) AS initial,
         LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH)+7, ISOWEEK) AS final
),
HelloWorld AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([DATE '2022-06-06']) shop_date, config
   WHERE shop_date >= config.initial AND shop_date <= config.final
)
SELECT * FROM HelloWorld;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I have tried that out and it does work. However, I was looking for something more concise. Is there any way I can do this without cross joining my variable table with the result I want to filter? Take into account that I am using this filter a lot.

Answer (score 0):

A few patterns I've used:

1. If you have many that have the same return type (STRING)

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION config(key STRING)
RETURNS STRING AS (
  CASE key
    WHEN "timezone" THEN "America/Edmonton"
    WHEN "something" THEN "Value"
  END
);
```

Then use config(key) to retrieve the value.

Or,

2. Create a function for each constant

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION timezone()
RETURNS STRING AS ("America/Edmonton");
```

Then use timezone() to get the value.

It would execute the function each time, so don't do something expensive in there (like SELECT from another table).